Networking error while connecting to S3 Bucket
I have created a S3 Bucket in my Free Tier account using CDK. I was able to access the Bucket via Console till yesterday, but when I tried to access it today it says Network error under AWS Region column and Bucket name is grayed out and can't click on it.
I have cleared all the browsing cookies and cache, used incognito mode, tried on different browser like chrome, safari and Firefox but no luck I see same error on all the browsers.
I have even tried resetting my internet connection. Can someone help on why i'm getting this error. I'm getting error on MAC book.
Thanks
Followed the instruction as suggested below link.
https://repost.aws/questions/QUmyiKwyQbQGSAPdUEvJ7wsw/s3-web-console-networking-error



Also I'm able to list the buckets from CLI
listing all the objects in a bucket
Ki ~ % aws s3 ls s3://cdk-hnb659fds-assets-905418062154-us-east-1
2024-12-11 15:44:37    3391575 07778a67e7379f6f5b6d25b9889544518771bc1223eb99ca4726a42c55d38667.zip
2024-12-11 15:00:44    3391421 2125dfa219ef0439c61f931682671b86f40f7dd60a3b6ac40d21f812cc6b1705.zip
2024-12-09 21:57:21    3899237 241f7d8fe6f8982a8bce1af7a41a9e1a2b7d2dd05df1d64fd9030750e56b7fc4.zip
2024-12-11 17:52:03      10279 25c9985cbf0819af1c15ef4bcba719360cceb8651f6aeadbcd658d33147475a5.json
2024-12-11 00:05:50    3390985 30a713af47f86b0638d74683a4055ff8d3229454be0a52611ecd329e08250343.zip
2024-12-09 21:57:21      10277 32a77dd5bc75a6db53666df9f315525dfc2888e2f254889cbed369f34bacd41b.json
2024-12-10 23:26:27      10277 340af5121199025607c485f6f7ae2267e5f47e69d124137378251496fad72a30.json
2024-12-11 15:20:45    3391634 3586a6f645b4d3082f2f43cedde543f156b4400a54eefdbba15d9cd0072fb934.zip
2024-12-11 17:52:03    3391777 3699728436892e3ad4fff92229a9c91d8b8aea51929a1abc1202e32a90827ba1.zip
2024-12-12 14:51:30    1888211 37f0839789acf937659ab8d83f812daf673b5c661858b24884aea3205d659d0f.zip
2024-12-11 15:00:44      10279 409b7aa3fd54f976a8c8af429fd3f78ea77f524da1153702242aa50bf964c3e9.json
2024-12-10 00:11:22    3390325 42f3da0db9178032869922b4b6e795da0a392f92bcf8a7ded64a8d1fe398816e.zip
2024-12-11 15:20:45      10279 58f0118f7ada128fe88f7f23163cfdcca667de148f6098e5a2b042df9ed14643.json
2024-12-11 00:05:50      10279 59f048704e2481e6ef3d79b5c585602d8bc1bc475f00e286224cc70f2f414d3d.json
2024-12-10 00:08:23      10277 61268798b091e4f2b93b5356d60b6997af38179dd7ecd5cdf70b76a79cd7b111.json
2024-12-10 23:41:14      10279 64d185f012f5e1798079eea84e508402fabd8842c31e9510be8e2350c8cb328f.json
Bucket policy
{
"Policy": "{"Version":"2012-10-17","Id":"AccessControl","Statement":[{"Sid":"AllowSSLRequestsOnly","Effect":"Deny","Principal":"","Action":"s3:","Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::cdk-hnb659fds-assets-905418062154-us-east-1","arn:aws:s3:::cdk-hnb659fds-assets-acc-num-us-east-1/*"],"Condition":{"Bool":{"aws:SecureTransport":"false"}}}]}"
}

Out of interest, does the awscli work? For example: aws s3 ls mybucket.

Hi @jarmod yes it works , please see screenshot above

That's a different level and only lists the buckets. I wanted to check an operation against the actual bucket e.g. list its objects or view its bucket policy. And have you tried from a different laptop?

Yeah! the issue is only MAC, on windows i don't see any issues at all

below is the bucket policy. {
"Policy": "{"Version":"2012-10-17","Id":"AccessControl","Statement":[{"Sid":"AllowSSLRequestsOnly","Effect":"Deny","Principal":"","Action":"s3:","Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::cdk-hnb659fds-assets-905418062154-us-east-1","arn:aws:s3:::cdk-hnb659fds-assets-905418062154-us-east-1/*"],"Condition":{"Bool":{"aws:SecureTransport":"false"}}}]}"
}

Hi @jarmod , please see above i can list all the objects in a bucket

Yes, all that's fine. Did you test S3 console from a different machine? If it works from the S3 console on a browser on a different machine then it would seem to be some issue with your machine. Weird that it's consistent across browsers and incognito mode though.

Yes it is weird, i'm having issues only MAC.. I have tried it on window using microsoft edge browser. I don't see any issues
